# Upload with php in Linux, the tmp_name is empty

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, upload

I am trying to upload a video using PHP 6.0, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 32 bit, but I can not upload.
Tmp_name is empty.
All possible problems have been resolved.

In php.ini, I configured correctly:

```
Php_value upload_max_filesize
Php_value post_max_size
```

In function tmp_error
The result was error 6.

Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.

Referred site: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Permissions granted on Linux:

```
Sudo chown -R www-data: www-data / tmp
Sudo chown -R www-data: www-data uploads

Sudo chmod 777 / tmp
Sudo chmod 777 uploads
```

Please someone could help me.

Comment: The spacing in your commands is wrong, it should be `www-data:www-data`. And you shouldn't be changing the ownership of the system's root directory.

Comment: If you truly did `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data / tmp` your Linux system could be severely damaged.

Comment: Please post the output from `ls -l /`

Comment: Barmar, sorry!
Because o command receive spacing. I no edit my command, but the command is join, like you posted. Thanks!
Michael Berkowski, whats directory you need to execute the command "ls -l"?
The damaged is about security?
Thanks to response!

Comment: I'm sorry.
I found the problem.
I config the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and forget of config the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
I need confi the directory /tmp in "upload_tmp_dir"
Michael Berlowski, whats permission is the best?
Thanks guy to help!

Comment: Be sure to use @ in the comments, so we receive notifications and can respond.  The way you had listed your `chown` commands with spaces, it appeared that you had set www-data ownership across your entire filesystem at its root `/` but if you typed those commands correctly, there should be no issue.

Comment: But you should not give www-data ownership of /tmp. If you modified the ownership of `/tmp` you should restore it to `root:root`.

Comment: Understand.
I can modify the www-data to other value?
Because it could be severely damaged.
Thanks very much to help and answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to the problem:**

**1º** Access the file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

**2º** In php.ini find the lines that contains:

**Memory_limit**

**Upload_max_filesize**

**Post_max_size**

Change the default values, for example:

**Memory_limit** = *100M*

**Upload_max_filesize** = *100M*

**Post_max_size** = *100M*

**3º** Find the line containing:

**Upload_tmp_dir**

Change the value to:

**Upload_tmp_dir** = */tmp*

**4th** Change permissions

Sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp
Sudo chown -R www-data:www-data uploads

Sudo chmod 644 /tmp
Sudo chmod 644 uploads

**5º** Repeat steps **1º** through **4º** in the file:

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

**6th** Restart Apache

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian
Sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

If you are using RedHat, Fedora or CentOS
Service httpd restart

Thanks very much